# Yeoman Angular, grunt server always launches IE

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular

Just started using Yeoman Angular generator, but when I run grunt server command, it always opens IE. Tried changes in GruntFile.js

```js
autoprefixer: {
    options: {
      browsers: ['last 1 version', 'Chrome']
    }
```

But it gives error
[image]

Any clues how to get it working?

Comment: Why are you tampering with `Autoprefixer`? That module is for CSS processing.

Comment: well i am completely new to this, i read somewhere that this bit controls what browser shall open, i want to use chrome and not IE. I have Chrome installed on my PC as well.

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#open - IE is probably your default browser. You might be able to open different browser via `appName` setting. But changing default browser if you are not using IE might be easier.

Comment: This is the place which you should be interested in - https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/templates/common/root/_Gruntfile.js#L89

Comment: OK, sounds logical, have started playing with this, lets see..

Answer (score 1):

Simply in your  Gruntfile.js you can add an app parameter:

```
open: {
  server: {
    url: 'http://localhost:XXXXXXXX',
    app: 'Google Chrome'
  }
},
```

This will work.
For reference check this link https://github.com/GabLeRoux/grunt-open/commit/6f2c7069767e58160ec96aaaa8fa20ed210ba183

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having problems, the following should work:

```
livereload: {
  options: {
    open: {
      appName: "google-chrome"
    },
```